# Getting duplicates from a data extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

We would need to extract duplicate values from our Marketing Cloud data extension and deliver them to our data team for review. The DE has about 34k contacts and only 3 fields: Account_ID, Phone_Number and Channel_Value. The Channel_Value can be either SMS or Viber. Now, using the code I will paste below, we managed to pinpoint duplicates but, honestly, we don't know how to extract all the instances of a duplicate record after using the PARTITION BY command. Namely, we need all instances of a duplicate (rowNumber= 1,2,3,...) not just after > 1. Here's a simple SQL we are using for this:

```
    SELECT
    Account_ID, 
    Channel_value, 
    Phone_Number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Phone_Number ORDER BY Channel_value) AS rowNumber
    FROM [Channel_Audience]
    WHERE Channel_value= 'SMS'    /* the second query is with WHERE = 'Viber' /
    AND rowNumber > 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ROW_NUMBER() function is great if you have an order that you need to find or maintain. However if you are looking to find duplicates (no order needed), then you should try the COUNT(*) function, as below:

```
SELECT
a.Account_ID
,a.Channel_value
,a.Phone_Number
,c.Instances
FROM [Channel_Audience] a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
  Channel_value
  ,Phone_Number
  ,COUNT(*) AS 'Instances'
  FROM [Channel_Audience]
  WHERE Channel_value = 'SMS'
  GROUP BY Channel_value, Phone_Number
) c ON c.Phone_Number = a.Phone_Number
WHERE a.Channel_value = 'SMS'
AND c.Instances > 1
```

**Explanation**
First you create a list of SMS Phone numbers with a COUNT(*) of how many time each number appears (the Inner Join part). Next you JOIN that COUNT value into your Channel_Audience where the value is greater than 1.

There are other ways to achieve this (see alternative below), however I personally prefer nested sub-queries.

**References**
[Nested Queries](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-sub-queries.htm)
[COUNT(*)](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_count.asp)
Alternative Solution: [HAVING COUNT()](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/count-having.php)